# The concept of ASP.NET Model design

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

First of all, this is 2nd week of my MVC learning and I'm very curious about designing a better website structure using MVC

In ASP.NET MVC framework, it is highly recommended to write most of business logic code into model but not controller, and my question is, what's the benefit behind it? Isn't it good to manipulate data in controller? Will that occupy more resources and times?

Any kind of ideas are welcomed. Please send me any article links if you have =]

Comment: No, it is not highly recommended to write most of your business logic code into the model.  Whoever told you that is wrong.

Comment: @MystereMan Mind elaborating on that? Where should business logic go, if not the model?

Comment: @Mansfield - Typically in a business layer.  In MVC, the Model is the presentation model, not the business model or domain model.  Only in very simplistic and trivial apps might they be the same.

Comment: @ Mystere Man Good point, but for example when user searching a list by entering keyword, which part deal with the filtering and sorting logic? should it be in model or controller?

Comment: @MystereMan It is not uncommon to hear the model is where you put your business logic. Wikipedia's MVC article indicates as such in the first paragraph (though I don't necessarily agree with it except in the smallest of apps as you say). I'd also suggest that, depending on your architecture, the Model could be your domain model/DTO, and your could create a custom ViewModel as your presentation model.

Comment: @user1804033 If you are filtering and sorting, that should be dealt with in the controller, which would pass the appropriate filtering and sorting criteria to your data access method. The controller mediates the conversation between your view and your model.

Comment: @ChrisHardie - MVC was originally envisioned as an entire application pattern, however most web applications these days are now n-tier and MVC is relegated to only the presentation tier.  This means the "model" becomes the presentation model only.  Your domain model (even that might be broken up into a data model and business model) often sits in its own layer.

Answer (score 2):

@MystereMan is only partially correct. In true-blue MVC pattern, yes, *all* business logic belongs on the model. I'm not talking about ASP.NET MVC, here, but the actual abstract MVC pattern.

In practice, the model is most generally a representation of a table row from your database, so it is many times not practical or even possible to place all your business logic in the "model". We tend to refer to a principally databased-backed "model" in this sense as an "entity". The entity is a "model" of your database state (or an alteration to that state in the case of an update). It's not really appropriate, in this sense, to tack on other logic not represented in or applicable to the database-layer.

This is why most developers will add in what's called a "view model", a concept borrowed somewhat from a pattern called MVVVM (Model-View-View Model). This pattern is an alternative to MVC, but the two are not mutually exclusive. In other words, it's possible, and many times even recommended to mix and match the concepts from both into a sort of hybrid pattern.

In ASP.NET MVC, this usually manifests as just the addition of a "view model" to the existing MVC structure. Your model becomes your database-backed entity, the view model will contain a subset of the model data needed for the view in context and any additional data or logic only relevant to said view, the view utilizes this view model to render itself and the controller still ties everything together.

The basic effect is the same, though. The view model essentially assumes the role of the "model" of MVC, and yes, all of your business logic should go here. A well designed view will have only the minimal amount of server-side code to render it; for loops, simple if statements, etc. are okay, but calculations are not. The controller's job is merely to return the response, which means fetching whatever the view needs to render itself. It should not know about your data, nor care what data is being interacted with. It just passes whatever it gets to the view and sends the response.

Comment: A very good point! you excellent answer makes me ask you an advanced question regarding to my current project: I'm writing a result page, when people entered the keyword and return the filtered list from database, but there is no way to store the sorted data list, when they click the 2nd page, the current list is gone and all items displayed again, as far as you know, is there a way to store the list somewhere in project?

Comment: I disagree.  I think that the trend has been to make models simple POCO's with metadata for validation.  Most business logic has moved to service layers which sit between your domain layer and get mapped to your view models.  The business logic is physically and logically separate from your actual domain model, and thus the logic is not part of the model.

Comment: @MystereMan: it's all semantics at this point. As I stated, in the actual MVC pattern, the "model" is responsible for *all* business logic. All we're talking about here now is what exactly is the "model". In my answer, I called it the view model. You're suggesting it's the service/DAL layer. It can be anything *except* the view or controller -- that's the important part.

Comment: @user1804033: you don't "store" the result list, you "store" the filters. Typically, you'll continue to pass them in the querystring or potentially use session variables (though querystring is the better practice). When you click the second page, you re-query based on those filters and select the next set of results.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - That's just it, you view "The Model" as a logical abstraction, while a newbie is quite literal about treating what's in the Model folder as "The Model".  I don't believe it's semantics at all really, and this is very confusing to newcomers to asp.net MVC.

Comment: @MystereMan - Well, if a newcomer takes "the model" literally, and only utilizes their entity models in the "Models" directory, then they should *still* put all the business logic on the "model", which in this case would be the actual model. Whatever the developer chooses as the "model", be it a view model, a DAL/service layer, or the actual entity model, regardless, all business logic belongs there. The argument you're making is that a DAL/service layer is more optimal than the entity model to be the "model" of MVC. That may be true, but has no bearing on the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

The point of MVC is separation of concerns - the controller should not know where the data comes from, or what format it's in, or what logic need be applied to retrieve it.

The model's job is to provide the data to the controller; no more, no less. The benefit is separation of concern - if you need to change business logic in the future you need only change it one place, in the model.

In terms of resources and time, I don't know that the program would necessarily be less efficient if data manipulation was done in the controller. But it would likely be poorly designed and be harder to maintain.

The [MVC wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is a good place to start.

Comment: good point! Say if I build a search page, once user enters the criteria, page will show a filtered records, in this case, controller will only take care of passing the criteria into the model while model should do the filter's job(DBContext.Table.Where()....)?

Comment: @user1804033 Exactly.

Comment: How stupid I am!!! I always did those things in my controller, but when creating a model from database(SQL Server), the model structure are very well built and packed, where can I write my business logic in? create a new class within the model and write data handling code in it?

Comment: @user1804033 it depends what your logic is. If it's fairly simple you can do it in the model. If it's more complex, you could have a separate data logic layer. But for your purposes I'd think the model could do the filtering and sorting (see chris's comment on your question.)

Answer (score 0):

The Idea is not resource utilization. But the idea is Separation of Concerns as mentioned by Mansfield.

Mostly people misunderstand term Model as data - Raw data. But that is not correct. Model is underlying Logical structure of data. Which means the data logically structured and filtered for the current context. Hence, only the processed data should come out of your Model.

Because of this Separation of Concern you can also do independent automated testing of the three parts. You can test you model completly independent from your Controller and vice-versa.

Comment: good point, so when user input some keyword to search a list on a page, which part should talk care of querying database?(DBcontext.DBset.where())? should it be in controller or model?

Answer (score 0):

So, where do you put your business logic? I've wrestled with this for a while, and I have come up with different locations based on the size and complexity of the app.

Tiny app: Put the business logic on your model using data annotations and implement the IValidatableobject interface for any custom rules you can't realise with the annotations.

Medium app: Build out a service layer, where your service objects act as gateways over your domain models, and can validate any business rules. Here is a great resource for that: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs

Big app: The service layer is now a facade over your business layer, where validation takes place in complex messaging frameworks and workflows.

I would point out that I like putting validation rules on my models/viewmodels, irrespective of the size of the app. I believe that they should know when they are in an error state, which is different than when a business rule has been violated.